# On any of my Heroku apps, several `heroku pg:` commands fail immediately with "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined."

Tags: postgresql, heroku

On any of my Heroku apps, several `heroku pg:` commands fail immediately with `Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined.`

For example:

```
$ heroku pg:push mydb DATABASE_URL -a $myapp
heroku-cli: Pushing mydb ---> postgresql-vertical-12345
 case 
------
 
(1 row)

 ▸    Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

---

```
$ heroku pg:ps -a $myapp
 ?column? 
----------
(0 rows)

 ▸    Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

This started within maybe the past two weeks. I have created/destroyed many apps, always with the same result. My goal is just to be able to push my local data. This error message doesn't exactly give me much in the way of next steps.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong (in which case, how do I fix it)?

Comment: My question is not related to the linked one.

Comment: I think it is. Looks like this is an issue inside heroku cli code

Comment: Is this all backtrace that you got? Can you try getting a more detailed log?